# Save elements from State to useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to pass all elements from a useSelector to a useRef (both arrays). When I console.log (code below) pokemonList.data, it shows me record, but I can't pass the data to the useRef (I've no idea why)

```
    const pokemonList = useSelector(state => state.PokemonList);
    const pokemons = useRef(new Array());

    console.log(pokemonList.data);
```

The console.log(pokemonList.data) shows:

{…}
​DefaultState: Object { loading: false, data: [], count: 0, … }
​count: 1118
​data: (20) […]
​​0: Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", … }
What I want is inside this array and inside data: (20) [...]

. And if I try to: pokemonList.data.map(el => pokemons.current.push(el.data)) it says that pokemonList has no Data...

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `useRef` at all?  Like to compare a current version to a previous version?  Otherwise you should just use the data from the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `console.log(pokemonList.data);` is showing that, then you'll need to make something like `pokemonList.data.data.map(`

What you can do is to save in Pokemon List `state.PokemonList.data` instead so you only have to make `pokemonList.data`

Comment: It worked! But my useRef array (that I'm feeding from pokemonList) is just getting the last results.. It changes. Look: pokemons.current = pokemonList.data;

I tried also to push the values, but dont work